# Creating a webservice inside a dll file? Can it be done?

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2010, dll

I would like to create a c# dll that handles requests.  I would like the requests to come as webservice calls so that websites can quickly call the dll.  Is there a way to integrate the two - to have the code for the webservice be placed inside of the dll?

Or, if the webservice has to be separate - is there a way with visual studio to put the webservice into the project with the dll but tell the compiler to compile it as an external file?  That way this would at least help me keep my project structure simple and clean.

Comment: What kind of service? WCF or legacy ASMX

Comment: I'm just looking to do async data transfer through jQuery/AJAX from my webpage and typically I would use a webservice to receive the call, process the info and return a value.  I would prefer to have the webservice be encapsulated inside of a compiled dll rather than right on a web page - but I'm not sure how to access the webservice if I do it that way.  any help, references are appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear to me what you're really trying to do. "A DLL that services requests" can be implemented in any number of ways.

One way to implement a Web service in a DLL would be to use an [HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx).

You'll have to supply more information about what exactly you're trying to do before we can provide reasonable answers.

Comment: I know that a webservice can be done in a webpage and is used by calling the web page itself.  I'm not familiar with any way to call a web service (for async data transfers) that resides in a compiled dll.  I thought I had read that it could be done, but can't seem to find any information online - perhaps its just a matter of knowing what to ask (which is why my question above is also vague).  I think the httpListener may be what I'm looking for - do you have any good reference sites that I can use to see it in action?

Comment: @Adam: I wrote a little about it here: http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=784  The code example is a console application, but it could just as easily be a method in a class library.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is create a new WCF Service Project. This will cause your services to be created as a separate application under IIS. Both projects would be in the same solution.

Comment: If I have an existing compiled dll that performs a certain set of functions already, is there a way to get this WCF Project to compile into the same dll?  Or, if not, will this WCF project compile to its own dll in the end?

Comment: What's your obsession with trying to use the same DLL? No, every project produces a separate DLL. That's how Visual Studio works.

Comment: Simply project requirements.  In the end, one dll file is/was requested.  this is one peice of a large system.

Comment: You have to push back on technology requirements which are simply impossible. What you're being asked to do just plain makes no sense in a .NET context. Maybe this makes sense in a Java world, but makes no sense at all with .NET. Quite possibly the people making this requirement don't know that it won't work, and someone has to tell them that.